# Support Vector - / Logistic - regression: do you have benchmark results for the boston housing data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, scikit-learn

I was going to test my implementation of the sklearn support vector regression package by running it on the boston housing prices dataset that ships with sklearn (sklearn.datasets.load_boston).

After playing around with it for a while (trying different regularization and tube parameters, randomization of cases and crossvalidation) and consistently predicting a flat line I am now at a loss for where I am failing. Even more striking is that when I use the diabetes dataset that also comes with the sklearn.datasets package (load_diabetes) I get a much nicer prediction.

Here is the code for replication:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import  load_boston
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# data = load_diabetes()
data = load_boston()
X = data.data
y = data.target

# prepare the training and testing data for the model
nCases = len(y)
nTrain = np.floor(nCases / 2)
trainX = X[:nTrain]
trainY = y[:nTrain]
testX  = X[nTrain:]
testY = y[nTrain:]

svr = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1000)
log = LinearRegression()

# train both models
svr.fit(trainX, trainY)
log.fit(trainX, trainY)

# predict test labels from both models
predLog = log.predict(testX)
predSvr = svr.predict(testX)

# show it on the plot
plt.plot(testY, testY, label='true data')
plt.plot(testY, predSvr, 'co', label='SVR')
plt.plot(testY, predLog, 'mo', label='LogReg')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Now my question is: **has anyone of you successfully used this dataset with a support vector regression model or has an idea of what I am doing wrong?** I am very thankful for your suggestions!

Here are the results of the above script this result:
[image: results of running on the load_boston dataset]

Comment: Linear regression != logistic regression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the kernel from `rbf` to `linear` will solve the problem. If you want to use `rbf`, try some different parameters, especially for `gamma`. The default `gamma` (`1/# features`) is too large for your case.

[image]

This is the parameter I used for linear kernel `SVR`:

```
svr = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1.0, epsilon=0.2)
```

I plotted both training data labels and testing data labels. You might notice that the distribution is not uniform for training data. This made the model lacks data for training when `5 < y < 15`. So I did some shuffling of data and set the training data to use 66% of your data.

```
nTrain = np.floor(nCases *2.0 / 3.0)
import random
ids = range(nCases)
random.shuffle(ids)

trainX,trainY,testX,testY = [],[],[],[]
for i, idx in enumerate(ids):
    if i < nTrain:
        trainX.append(X[idx])
        trainY.append(y[idx])
    else:
        testX.append(X[idx])
        testY.append(y[idx])
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Visually it looks better for both regressors in terms of prediction errors.

Here is one working example of `rbf` kernel `SVR`:

```
svr = SVR(kernel='rbf',  C=1.0, epsilon=0.2, gamma=.0001)
```

The result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Why is the load_diabetes() dataset not labelled? Isn't it a cardinal sin in data science to have unlabeled axes/unlabeled data? I am using the diabetes data set for a mandatory school project and I can't find a single source that would help me understand what all these floating point numbers represent, and it is quite frustrating! It seems to me that given how many different professors through the years explained how unlabeled axes are a cardinal sin in mathematics, it doesn't seem very far-removed that a data set without a keys() fnct that indicates what the columns represent is just as bad..